# Disable password prompt for encrypted LUKS partiton after setting up automatic decryption with TPM2

Tags: boot, grub2, encryption, tpm

I have a setup with an unencrypted EFI boot partition and an encrypted LVM volume.
Secure boot is enabled and I have installed tpm2-toos and configured automatic decryption for the partition with clevis (following this guide: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/194081/use-tpm2-0-to-securely-decrypt-the-hard-drive-in-linux-unattended)

It works fine, but on boot grub still asks me to enter the disk password manually. There is a couple seconds delay before the disk gets automatically decrypted and the boot continues normally. Is there a way to disable this password prompt and only show it when necessary (e.g. if automatic decryption fails for some reason)?

Thank you!

(I know this is a bit of a nitpicky and purely cosmetic issue x)